# VB.Net Debugger First Executed Statement

Tags: vb.net, debugging

Is there any way to get the debugger to automatically step into each line as soon as you start it? I have to trace through a jumbled mess of code, and it would save me a lot of time if the debugger essentially set a break point at the beginning of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Run your project with `F8` "Step Into" and it will break at the first statement.

Comment: @SLaks Depends on environment, in VB environment it's F8, in C# it's F11

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and the function key doesn't appear to work for the "Step Into" feature. However, I was able to use "Step Over," and I think this is sufficient for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: F11 works in VB as well, so I'd get used to that.